app-ads.txt tab in the AdMob console is not showing anything
my app-ads.txt tab in the AdMob console is not showing anything. I have not published my app on Google Play or the App Store;
it is currently in internal testing. Is this the reason? Ads are only seen on Android, while the iOS side is not showing any ads.
